# Why is it that for electromagnetic waves, there are always two independent modes, or polarisations, per state?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation, polarization, degrees-of-freedom

**Context**

I was looking for a good derivation of Planck's law.  In [1], it states

> ``Finally, for electromagnetic waves, we are always allowed two independent modes, or polarisations, per state...''

**Question**

How come, for electromagnetic waves we are always allowed two independent modes, or polarisations, per state?

**Bibliography**

[1]
https://edisciplinas.usp.br/pluginfile.php/48089/course/section/16461/qsp_chapter10-plank.pdf

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/395284/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I read the post cited by Qmechanic before posting my question. As far as I am concerned, that post does not answer my question. However, @Thomas Fritsch did answer my question.

Comment: Since I have been prevented from posting questions on this chatboard, I have begun to go through my questions. I have reread the duplicative post referred to herein. While, I agree that my question is duplicative, the answer posted there by @knzhou does not inform in the same way that Thomas Fritsch's does. Thomas Fritsch, if you think the questions is duplicative, please delete your answer here, and repost it at the duplicative site. In such case, I can delete this question in the hope of earning back my "ask a question" privaledge. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider for example an electromagnetic wave in $z$-direction. Then the two polarizations are:

- $\mathbf E$ in $x$ direction and $\mathbf B$ in $y$ direction
- $\mathbf E$ in $y$ direction and $\mathbf B$ in $x$ direction